# SubdivisionSurface modifier doesn't work properly on new version of blender

Tags: modifiers

[image: Version 3.4.1][image: Version 2.93.9]

On v2.93.9 work fine but ob the new one...

Comment: Hello, maybe a problem of GPU driver? See here: https://developer.blender.org/T100964

Comment: It's definitely not a general problem of the Blender version, because I use 3.4.1 as well and it works all fine like expected.

Comment: @moonboots Thank you so much! Turning off gpu subdivision works good for me. Now I can freely use this modifier again.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://developer.blender.org/T100964):

Upgrade your GPU driver to fix this problem: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/gpu/index.html

You can also fix this by turning off GPU subdivision with current drivers: *Edit → Preferences → Viewport → Subdivision → GPU Subdivision*